# Rock, Paper And Scissors Program (Upper And Lower Case Problem)

Tags: python

I Was Practicing Programs Of Python And Then I Made This Rock, Paper, Scissors Program. And The Program Is Running Perfectly But The Problem Is Like This:
I Chose "Rock, Paper, Scissors" Like This Than It Runs. 
But If I Enter Rock, Paper, Scissors In Any Other Way It Prints The Else Statment i.e., Invalid Choice.
I Want To Use Upper/Lower Case But How And Where.

```
import random

user = input("""Tell Me What Do You Choose:
        ~Rock
        ~Paper
        ~Scissors. 
        -> I Choose : """)
choose = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
computer = random.choice(choose)
print(f"Computer Chose {computer}.")
#Function To Compare Choices
def compare(user, computer):
    if user == computer:
       return("It's A Tie :(....")
    elif user == "Rock":
         if computer == "Scissors":
             return("User Wins!")
         else:
             return("Computer Wins!")
    elif user == "Scissors":
         if computer == "Paper":
             return("User Wins!")
         else:
             return("Computer Wins!")
    elif user == "Paper":
         if computer == "Rock":
             return("User Wins!")
         else:
             return("Computer Wins!")

    else:
        return("User Choose Out Of The Options!")
        exit()
print(compare(user, computer))
```

Comment: process all the comparing data in lower case only, it will be helpful for you

Comment: Do the same for the text in your question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just transform your input into lowercase with the [`lower()` method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_lower.htm)

```
user = user.lower()
```

that makes `sCiSsOrS` into `scissors`
you also need to adjust your if statements to be all lowercase

```
elif user == "Rock": --> elif user == "rock":
```

Comment: It Is Now Working But Now The "Tie" Condition Is Not Working:                                         
 ` if user == computer:
       return("It's A Tie :(....")`   @xSparfuchs

Comment: every word in choose[] must be lowercase

Comment: Uh Huh... Doesn't Work. The Tie Condition Is Not Working. @xSparfuchs

Comment: Oh, I Found The Mistake. I Forgot To Lowercase The If-Else Condition. Anyway, It Is Working Now. @xSparfuchs

Comment: Great, glad i could help. You can mark the question as answered btw.